# console.log and alert returns undefined

Tags: javascript

This is a basic question about javascript as I am new I would like to try out different things as I used to do in C. So now my Question is when I use

```js
console.log(alert())
```

I get the result `undefined`. Do these functions return no values? If they return values what are those and why I can't check them in the console. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because `alert()` doesn't return anything ?

Comment: Alert does not return anything. It is just a information to the user. In theory the `alert` does not even need to result into a pause/blocking until it is closed. The browser do blocking only due to backwards compatibility.

Comment: I have a C background hence I assumed that using this combination would provide some return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each function in JavaScript returns a value. If you haven't provided an explicit one, it returns `undefined`. So `alert` works and its returned value which is `undefined` is passed to the `console.log`.

Check this.

```js
function foo() {

}

let result = foo();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `If you haven't provided an explicit one` -> should be noted that you can't influence that value in the case of `alert` **and** that `alert` is native code

Comment: @Adelin It's obvious.

Comment: @Adelin are you defining `alert` anywhere? If not, then it logically follows that you wouldn't be providing a return value, either. You can, however, overwrite `alert`, with something like `origAlert = alert; window.alert = input => origAlert(input); return input;`

Comment: its obvious to you, not to OP :), since he asked such an obvious question - so if you answer obvious questions, provide obvious answers

Answer (score 3):

`alert` always returns `undefined`, as does `console.log`.

If you wanted to save the input from the user in a variable, use `prompt`:

```js
const str = prompt('Input something');
console.log('str is', str);
```

(Or, even better, use a proper modal instead - `alert`, `prompt` and `confirm` are all considered poor practice because they *block*)

Answer (score 1):

alert(message);

This shows a message and pauses script execution until the user presses “OK”.
it means it expect a string to be pass as a parameter which will be displayed in the prompts

ref = > https://javascript.info/alert-prompt-confirm.

Comment: The pausing of the script execution for `alert` is optional [whatwg: alert(message)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert), `8. Optionally, pause while waiting for the user to acknowledge the message.` The browser vendors could also implement it as some kind of notification bubble. While it is true that current browser all pause the execution it is not something that you should rely on.